# For development in Xcode 10.x, how well does the git integration work with github?

Tags: xcode, git, github, version-control

Since Apple has pulled subversion integration from Xcode (and Perforce never choose to directly support that integration since Xcode 3), it seems as if git is the only fully integrated source code control system for MacOS and IOS development.

***How well does Xcode 10.x integration work with GitHub?***

In addition to Xcode's integration, ***what are some polished MacOS apps that serve as stand-alone git clients?***

My experience with the git command line has not been great: I'm always getting into trouble where the repository gets messed up ("detached heads", for example) and it seems to take someone with a PhD in git to get me back to a functional, stable repository.  ***Will GitHub help in those situations?***

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 10 integration with git is very intuitive and reliable. You can use Xcode for commit, push and see history of commits and so forth. Also Github macOS application works fine but I personally prefer Xcode to do so.

Comment: Is that GitHub MacOS application a real standalone app, or a web app?

Comment: It is native application build using web framework called Electron.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode 10.2.1 with git and GitHub, brought me many troubles. I lost one day of development, because even though committing seemed fine inside Xcode, no commit was performed on the local .git repository nor on the remote Github repository.
The only way to recover a proper functionality was to checkout to the last committed version and loose all the job in between.

I have not been able to figure out the exact cause, but I noticed that opening several projects in Xcode and/or using playgrounds while developing on a project seems to corrupt Xcode git functionality. Quitting and relaunching Xcode corrects the trouble, most of the time ...

Comment: Oh, that's not good.  Was it working with a previous 10.x version of Xcode?  If you're a developer, it might be a good idea to file a report with the Apple bug reporting system (Radar?)

Comment: I do development as a hobby and I'm quite new to Xcode and Swift, although I've dealt with some Objective C in the past. I have a very low experience with Xcode and the latest version is the one I've had the longest experience with (a few weeks!). I don't even know how to report bug to Apple. The only thing I know is that I usually need to quit Xcode and relaunch it before being able to commit changes.

Comment: OK -- sounds like I need to speak with GitHub support.  If there's some issue with Xcode, they've undoubtably heard about it.  Similarly, if there's a bug that serious in Xcode 10.2.x, I'm guessing Apple will push an update soon.

Comment: Hi - I did some search and apparently it is a known bug since Xcode 10.2 as related I this post on Apple developper's forum https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115298